# arr1=(1 2 3) ; arr2=${arr1[@]} equal but different

Tags: shell-script

I make such an array

```
$ arr1=(1 2 3) ; arr2=${arr1[@]}
```

Use iteration to check them

```
$ for i in $arr1; do echo $i; done
1

$ for i in $arr2; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

They are equall

```
$ if [[ $arr1==$arr2 ]];then echo yes ;fi
yes
```

How should I understand this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things which needs to be fixed here.

1. When you say you make arrays `arr1` and `arr2` are the same. No they are *not*. The declaration of `arr1` is valid but `arr2` is not! It is a string. Doing the below assigns the output of array expansion of `arr1` as a string.

   ```
   arr2=${arr1[@]}
   declare -p arr2
   declare -- arr2="2 3 4"
   ```

   To declare it as an array you need to have the `(..)` present and quote the array expansion of `arr1` properly to preserve the separation of the elements.

   ```
   arr2=("${arr1[@]}")
   declare -p arr2
   declare -a arr2='([0]="2" [1]="3" [2]="4")'
   ```
2. Iterating over an array using `for i in $arr1; do echo $i; done` is does not work. It is an incorrect construct in `bash`, which is somehow translating to `${arr1[0]}`. The right syntax to use is

   ```
   for i in "${arr1[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
   ```

   The loop over `arr2` is again incorrect. You may assume the loop is done on an array. But it is a string. It is done on a single string that is split by spaces. You need to first convert `arr2` to proper array format and iterate as I've mentioned above.
3. The equality check is also incorrect, since `if [[ $arr1==$arr2 ]]` compares for non zero string length, i.e. the whole of `$arr1==$arr2` is treated as one whole string by `[[` operator and that's why you are seeing a positive condition match for it. The same would be failed if you had used the basic `test` operator `[`. The right way to compare two arrays would be iterate one over the other and do an equality match.

Comment: See also `a=$(typeset -p arr1) b=$(typeset -p arr2); [ "${a#*=}" = "${b#*=}" ]` to compare two arrays, both keys and values, remember arrays in bash (inspired from ksh's) are sparse arrays, some sort of associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers, not the normal arrays one may be used to in other shells or other languages.

Answer (score 2):

The error is your condition:

```
[[ $arr1==$arr2 ]]
```

will expand to:

```
[[ 1==1 2 3 ]]
```

which equivalent to:

```
[[ -n 1==1 2 3 ]]
```

which is true.

---

Also note that even with the right syntax:

```
[[ $arr1 == $arr2 ]]
```

that condition compare the first element of array `arr1` which is `1`, with the string `arr2`, which is `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equal,

```
arr1=(1 2 3)
arr2=${arr1[@]}

if [[ $arr1 == $arr2 ]];then ## Space is required here ( $arr1 == $arr2)
  echo yes 
fi
```